# Not use numbers over 999 with point in template Django

Tags: python, django

The problem is:

When I have more than 999 elements in a table in DB,example, 1000, 1001...2000, etc, the id in DB  is saved without point, but when I try to use this id in template it is converted with point, example, 1.000, 1.001...2.000. I fixed the problem using a 'safe' filter.

Note: I realized that use point or comma depending of language, for example in english is shown in template as '1,100' (one thousand one hundred).

```
{{ value.id|safe }}
```

But, I think it is not the solution, because is not scalable for others functionalities. It cloud be present in others parts of code that I didn't kwow.

Why Django do it?, is a bug, I do not understand why it happen.

Is there another solution, for example a configurable value in settings?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please clarify "saved without point". Do you mean as a decimal/floating point integer? A PK id should only be an integer. Not sure I'm following what you're asking otherwise.

Comment: Ok, in DB is saved without point, I need show it in template the same way that is saved in DB, without point, example, '1000', not '1.000'. Sorry for my english, is not my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default settings.py file created by `django-admin.py startproject` includes `USE_L10N = True` for convenience. Note, however, that to enable number formatting with thousand separators it is necessary to set `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True` in your settings file. Alternatively, you could use `intcomma` to format numbers in your template.

It sounds like what you need to do is to set `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False`

I presume that you've either globally loaded internationalization in your project or in the template with:

```
{% load l10n %}
```

So to unlocalize this value use:

```
{{ value.id|unlocalize }}
```

[See the Django documentation for more information.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, 'USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False' worked for me.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, consider marking it as the accepted answer so that others know that it worked (in case they are having the same problem and find this question in a search).